# Edit lone address in bytes class

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

So in python a variable can be things like strings or integers. There is also one called bytes. This is as you'd expect: bytes. So I have some bytes in hexadecimal `\x0B\x90\x01\x08\x2C...` and I want to edit it. More specifically, edit only one of those. I've tried stuff like:

```py
var[3] = b'23'
```

and lots of others with things like:

```py
bytes(), list(), and more
```

Yet none of them work.

How would I go about editing lone bytes in a variable of the bytes class?

Comment: P.S. If I need to add any more info please do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: Use a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray)